# Error when switching to another Activity unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, module

In my project there are two modules of the application. When I try to use Intent to go from the Activity of one module to the Activity of another module I get an error that the second Activity is not found in the Manifest. But this Activity is registered in the Manifest of the second module. I have already tried all the answers from similar questions, but the problem remains

My Intent function:

```
public void SendToMetronomeActivity() {
        Intent mMetronomeIntent = new Intent();
        mMetronomeIntent.setClassName("com.infernal93.metronome.activities", "MainMetronomeActivity");
        startActivity(mMetronomeIntent);
    }
```

Manifest of the second module:

```
<activity android:name="com.infernal93.metronome.activities.MainMetronomeActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Error:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.infernal93.metronome.activities/MainMetronomeActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4028)
        at androidx.fragment.app.j.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3989)
        at androidx.fragment.app.j.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4312)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4280)
        at com.mib.livepartiture.Live.MainActivity.y(MainActivity.java:1356)
```

New error:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.infernal93.metronome.activities.MainMetronomeActivity }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your activity like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainMetronomeActivity"
        android:label="Preferences" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.infernal93.metronome.activities.MainMetronomeActivity />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and use it:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.infernal93.metronome.activities.MainMetronomeActivity");
```