# How to use IntentLauncher in ReactNative expo?

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

I try to use [IntentLauncher](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#intentlauncherstartactivityasyncactivityaction-params) to open app by package name in my expo app (without experience in native android). I follows these steps.

- create native android app and log the intent from getLaunchIntentForPackage, this is the result `Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.application.myapp cmp=com.application.myapp/.MainActivity }`. This intent can launch app perfectly.
- use data from above intent to call `IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync` in my expo app

```js
IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
  "android.intent.action.MAIN",
  {
    category: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER",
    packageName: "com.application.myapp",
    flags: 268435456,
    className: ".MainActivity"
  }
)
```

But above code return `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.application.myapp/.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In your manifest, you have to declare the app intent you're to launch, see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989969/error-when-switching-to-another-activity-unable-to-find-explicit-activity-class